# Parse XML and save into object

Tags: c#

I would like to parse an XML file and save this information into object. What is the best way to do this? Please let me know.

Thank you..

Comment: I am guessing you mean you want to serialize xml into an object not just load it into an xmlDocument object, correct?

Comment: @CSharpAtl: I misunderstood it too;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using .Net 3.5, I would suggest using LINQ-To-XML.

A simple example...

XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
 <People>
      <Person>
          <Name> ABC </Name>
          <SSN> 111111 </SSN>
          <Address> asdfg </Address>
      </Person>
 </People>
```

LINQ query

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(pathToFile);
var query = from d in doc.Root.Descendants("Person")
            select d;

foreach (var q in query)
{
    string name = q.Element("Name").Value;
    string ssn = q.Element("SSN").Value;
    string address = q.Element("Address").Value;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use XmlSerializer to deserialize it.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class MyType
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = @"<Root>
                          <Id>1</Id>
                          <Name>The Name</Name>
                      </Root>";
        MyType obj = (MyType) new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType))
            .Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I heard LINQ is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the schema (or an xml file) and generate a class from that with **[xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)**. The generated code will be ugly, you may need to clean it up by hand.
2. Use [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to deserialize into an instance.

The advantage of this method over others is that you get a strongly typed object (and IntelliSense working on your object). Among other things it means that the "node lookup" is faster than at other solutions (which mostly use a dictionary).

Or you might give a try to dynamic keyword of C# 4.0, it may give you a choice to avoid generating the code and just deserialize at runtime. I'm not sure about that though. That way you lose strong typing, but keep the syntax.