# read XML using LINQ

Tags: c#

I am newbie to LINQ. I am trying to read the following node and element values from XML using LINQ.

DATA -- msgid and msgtime
PTP -- percentage
CONT1 -- get "url" value if the "type" = "RIGHT"

Please let me know.

```
<DATA msgid="02123" msgtime="2008-02-29 15:30:02.123">
  <PTP number="67" pert="READ" percentage="95" pertime="2008-02-29 15:30:02.123">
    <Images>
      <Image view="w1" type="IMAGE" percentage="85" distance="0" url="00002_tyd.jpg" />
    </Images>
  </PTP>
  <CHAS1 sequence="1" number="58019" percentage="95" pertime="2008-02-29 15:30:02.123">
    <Images>
      <Image view="c1" type="WRONG" percentage="85" url="00002_ssj.jpg" />
      <Image view="c2" type="RIGHT" percentage="85" url="00003_ssj.jpg" />
    </Images>
    <CONT1 number="58011" percentage="95" pertime="2008-02-29 15:30:02.123">
      <Images>
        <Image view="c1" type="WRONG" percentage="85" url="00002_csj.jpg" />
        <Image view="c2" type="RIGHT" percentage="85" url="00003_csj.jpg" />
      </Images>
    </CONT1>
  </CHAS1>
</DATA>
```

Comment: <DATA msgid="02123" msgtime="2008-02-29 15:30:02.123">
  <PTP number="67" pert="READ" percentage="95" pertime="2008-02-29 15:30:02.123">
    <Images>
    </Images>
  </PTP>
  <CHAS1 sequence="1" number="58019" percentage="95" pertime="2008-02-29 15:30:02.123">
    <CONT1 number="58011" percentage="95" pertime="2008-02-29 15:30:02.123">
      <Images>
        <Image view="c1" type="WRONG" percentage="85" url="00002_csj.jpg" />
        <Image view="c2" type="RIGHT" percentage="85" url="00003_csj.jpg" />
      </Images>
    </CONT1>
  </CHAS1>
</DATA>

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537831/parse-xml-and-save-into-object/1537903#1537903

Comment: @nav100 -  Reformatted to reveal XML. You can use the code button (the 1010 button) to do this

Comment: @nav100 - are you wanting to read a specific node?  Is that the entire file?

Comment: yes. I want to read a specific node. It's not the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at this:

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx

Particularly the part beginning with "Once these files are loaded into the LINQ to XML API, you can write queries over that tree."

Based on that, something like this should work for you:

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"C:\data.xml");
var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("DATA")
        select new 
        {
            MsgId = (int)c.Attribute("msgid"),
            MsgTime = (DateTime)c.Attribute("msgtime"),
            PtpPercentage = (int)c.Element("PTP").Attribute("percentage")
            ContUrls = from i in c.Element("CHAS1")
                                  .Element("CONT1")
                                  .Descendants("Image")
                       where (string)i.Attribute("type") == "RIGHT"
                       select (string)i.Attribute("url");
        };
```

Not tested, but that should put you on the right track.